# Read dom from Firefox Add-on on click

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I build a small add-on for firefox and for this I need to get elements from the site's dom.

So I try:

```
var pMScript = "self.port.emit('data',[ document.getElementById('mainphoto').src, document.getElementById('mainphoto').alt, document.URL.toString() ] );"

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: 'http://500px.com/*',
  contentScript: pMScript,
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on('data', function(pageInfo) {
      userData = pageInfo;
    });
  }
});
```

But this works only in the exports.main function, when I load the page but I want read the dom of the current tab when I click the button.

**How can I accomplish this?**

I use:
The builder.addons.mozilla.org and the sdk 1.14